# Using client-side state with Ember.js

Tags: ember.js

I've inherited some Ember.js code that is used in part to maintain an online shopping cart.  The problem is that the current code base does not maintain the state of shopping cart content anywhere but in the model, and so when the user reloads the page (via the browser's reload function) anything that was already in the cart is lost and its value resets.

For better or worse this application was written as a thick-client with almost nothing but user authentication details and reference data stored on the backend.

My question is: is this the normal approach for Ember applications?  And if so, what is Ember's best practice for maintaining session state across browser actions that don't directly interface with Ember's router?  I figured a short-term band-aid might be to stuff the cart contents into a cookie on the client side, but there seems to be little in the way of cookie management in Ember.js, and it also seems somewhat inconsistent in spirit.

Thanks.

Comment: Answers here are going to be opinion-based... A cookie would work, but if the user switches to another machine the shopping cart will be empty. If you want to persist the shopping cart, you'll likely want to create a new model to store the user's latest cart contents. If you want to maintain that model during the session without interacting with the router, you can bind the model to the highest-level controller (likely the application controller), and then access via something like `this.get('controllers.application.cart')`. I don't think there is a right "Ember-way" answer to this, though...